# Deleting admin account in ObjectGears

Tags: administrator, objectgears

After starting ObjectGears the first time I created administrator as the first user. I configured everything with this user and then imported other users.

Now I do not know if I can delete this user. I do not want to lose admin access.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it. The fact that some account is admin is set in the file web.configu in the parameter AdminLogins. So admin can be anybody who has the account included here.

You can also leave this parameter blank and then nobody will be able to change any configuration in the instance, supposing you also delete model owners.